# Vue return undefined during emit event

Tags: vue.js, vue-class-components, vue-property-decorator

I read a code, where it allows user to download attachment

```html
  <template #link="{ item, rowdata }">
    <attachment-link
      v-test-id="'attachment-link'"
      :inventory-id="item"
      :filename="rowdata['fileName']"
      @download-attachment="downloadAttachment">
    </attachment-link>
  </template>
```

But in the `downloadAttachment` function, it returns `undefined`, why the emit still works?

```js
@Emit('download')
private downloadAttachment(filename: string, attachmentId: string) {
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Because emitted events are allowed to emit **no** data - i.e. an `undefined` value.

Comment: then in the parent, what is the emitted value? undefined? i could not understand the use case for this

Comment: It's probably demonstrating something else rather than downloading the file - otherwise there would have been shown the actual code that downloads the file. Perhaps the download ifunction s left as exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `return undefined` line is rather redundant because that's the default behavior in a function that has no `return` statement.

The return value of the `@Emit`-decorated function does *not* cause an `undefined` value to be emitted. When the function returns nothing (i.e., `undefined`), the [original event arguments from the caller are emitted](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/blob/d7954f8/src/decorators/Emit.ts#L20), which enables event forwarding. On the other hand, when the function returns any non-`undefined` value (even `null`), [only that value is emitted](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/blob/d7954f8/src/decorators/Emit.ts#L39).

So in your specific example, the `<attachment-link>`'s `download-attachment` event is forwarded as the `download` event from the component. The emitted event data would still be `filename` and `attachmentId`.